# Change to normal mode when MacVim goes background

Tags: vim, macvim

Is there any way to leave insert mode automatically once MacVim is put in background, so when I came back it's in normal mode?

Often I change the foremost application an once I come back to MacVim I see myself inserting lots of 'j's and 'k's. It would be best practice to get more habituated to press , but it would save some strokes specially when working on a website which needs a lot of edit/refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to quote https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968548/vim-return-to-command-mode-when-focus-is-lost:

The following autocommand would be the "obvious" choice.

```
au FocusLost,TabLeave * stopinsert
```

Unfortunately, it only seems to be working properly for TabLeave. The FocusLost event is triggering but for some reason the stopinsert command isn't actually taking effect until after a key event is received once Vim has regained focus.

Instead, you can take advantage of feedkeys and the "Get me to normal mode no matter what!" key combo:

```
au FocusLost,TabLeave * call feedkeys("\<C-\>\<C-n>")
```

The only downside is that feedkeys() requires at least Vim 7. This shouldn't be a big deal, though, since Vim7 was released back in 2006.

Comment: Thanks akira. Is this a StackOverflow question?

Comment: @sidyll: at least i dont think so. it fits more here than over there.